# Scala: Most idiomatic way to conditionally execute one Future depending on another?

Tags: scala, future

What is the most idiomatic and concise way to perform the following: One future that may or may not execute depending or a result of a previous future execution, like so:

```
def getItFromHere : Future[Option[Something]] = ...

def getItFromThere : Future[Option[Something]] = ...

def getIt : Future[Option[Something]] = {

    for {
        maybeSomething <- getItFromHere
        probablySomething <- maybeSomething.getOrElse(getItFromThere) // Obviously can't be done!!!
    }
    yield probablySomething
}
```

A specific use-case example:
Get an item from cache and only if it wasn't found in cache, get it from the database.

I'm taking an assumption here that `getItFromHere` and `getItFromThere` will not fail with an exception. They will either return Some[Something] or None. Feel free to take this assumption into account, or giving a better without it.

Note: I understand the internal mechanics of for-comprehension which is actually translated to map/flatMap/filter internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your example is almost there. You only need to match the Future type expected by the monadic composition:

```
for {
     fut <- someFuture
     something <- fut.map(x=>someFuture).getOrElse(someBetterFuture)
} yield something
```

For the sake of simplicity, here `someFuture` is a `val`. If you use a `def`, avoid re-calculating the operation by packaging your result back into a future. Folding that into the  question's code:

```
for {
     maybeSomething <- getItFromHere
     probablySomething <- maybeSomething.map(x=> Future.succcessful(maybeSomething)).getOrElse(getItFromThere)
} yield probablySomething
```

Answer (score 6):

You could fail the future if no item is found in the cache and then recover it with the retrieval.

```
// assuming getItFromHere() fails if no item is found
getItFromHere() recoverWith { case _ => getItFromThere() }
```

Or with the `Option` you could do it like this:

```
getItFromHere() flatMap {
  case Some(x) => Future.successful(Some(x))
  case None => getItFromThere()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @drexin. maasg answer was what I had in mind, but your answer is correct and I upvoted it. One inaccuracy: You should return Future.successful(Some(x))

Answer (score 2):

if you use the OptionT transformer from scalaz:

```
def getItFromHere : OptionT[Future,Something] = OptionT(...)

def getItFromThere : OptionT[Future,Something] = OptionT(...)

def getIt : Future[Option[Something]] = (getItFromHere orElse getItFromThere).run
```